# Application freeze when redirecting STDOUT of child process in some cases

Tags: c++, winapi

OK, so the basic task for me is to create function that will run a process and grab console output (stdout and stderr) from it with possibility to specify created process execution timeout.

First approach was to create temporary file (with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`) and specify it as `hStdOutput/hStdError` for `STARTUPINFO`, wait for process and read file's content. This works fine. But I don't like the idea of temporary file creation. I found the example from msdn with redirecting console output using pipes (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)). Here is rewritten/fixed code (as command line tool for tests):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <cassert>

#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>


using string_t = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;

#define THROW_E(X) throw std::runtime_error{(X) + std::string(": ") + std::to_string(::GetLastError())};
#define THROW(X) throw std::runtime_error{(X)};

namespace {

// From
// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx
void ArgvQuote(
    const string_t& Argument,
    string_t& CommandLine,
    bool Force)
{
    if (Force == false &&
        Argument.empty () == false &&
        Argument.find_first_of (_T(" \t\n\v\"")) == Argument.npos)
    {
        CommandLine.append (Argument);
    }
    else {
        CommandLine.push_back (_T('"'));

        for (auto It = Argument.begin () ; ; ++It) {
            unsigned NumberBackslashes = 0;

            while (It != Argument.end () && *It == _T('\\')) {
                ++It;
                ++NumberBackslashes;
            }

            if (It == Argument.end ()) {
                CommandLine.append (NumberBackslashes * 2, _T('\\'));
                break;
            }
            else if (*It == _T('"')) {
                CommandLine.append (NumberBackslashes * 2 + 1, _T('\\'));
                CommandLine.push_back (*It);
            }
            else {
                CommandLine.append (NumberBackslashes, _T('\\'));
                CommandLine.push_back (*It);
            }
        }
        CommandLine.push_back (_T('"'));
    }
}
using handle_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, decltype(&::CloseHandle)>;

handle_ptr CreateHandlePtr(HANDLE h)
{
    return handle_ptr{h, &::CloseHandle};
}

handle_ptr CreateChildProcess(string_t cmd_line, handle_ptr&& std_out, const string_t& dir)
{
    assert(!cmd_line.empty());
    assert(std_out.get());

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = std_out.get();
    si.hStdOutput = std_out.get();
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    LPTSTR p_cmd_line = &cmd_line[0];
    auto created = CreateProcess(NULL, 
        p_cmd_line,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        TRUE, // Handles are inherited 
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        NULL, // Use parent's environment 
        dir.empty() ? nullptr : dir.c_str(),
        &si,
        &pi);
    if(!created)
        THROW_E("CreateProcess()");

    std_out.reset();
    ::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return CreateHandlePtr(pi.hProcess);
}

std::string ReadFromPipe(handle_ptr&& std_out)
{
    std::string content;
    DWORD read = 0;
    CHAR buf[1 * 1024] = {};
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    for(;;)
    {
        success = ::ReadFile(std_out.get(), buf, _countof(buf), &read, nullptr);
        if(!success && (::GetLastError() != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE))
            THROW_E("ReadFile()");

        if(!success || (read == 0))
            break;
        content.append(buf, read);
    }

    return content;
}

} // namespace

std::string ConsoleOutFromExec(const string_t& cmd_line, std::size_t timeout_msecs = INFINITE,
    const string_t& directory = string_t{})
{
    auto child_stdout_r = CreateHandlePtr(nullptr);
    auto child_stdout_w = CreateHandlePtr(nullptr);
    {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {};
        sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

        HANDLE raw_child_stdout_r = nullptr;
        HANDLE raw_child_stdout_w = nullptr;
        if(!::CreatePipe(&raw_child_stdout_r, &raw_child_stdout_w, &sa, 0))
            THROW_E("CreatePipe()");
        child_stdout_r = CreateHandlePtr(raw_child_stdout_r);
        child_stdout_w = CreateHandlePtr(raw_child_stdout_w);

        if(!::SetHandleInformation(child_stdout_r.get(), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
            THROW_E("SetHandleInformation()");
    }

    auto child_proc = CreateChildProcess(cmd_line, std::move(child_stdout_w), directory);
    auto status = ::WaitForSingleObject(child_proc.get(), timeout_msecs);
    switch(status)
    {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            break;
        default:
            THROW("WaitForSingleObject()");
    }

    return ReadFromPipe(std::move(child_stdout_r));
}

std::size_t ParseTimeout(const string_t& str)
{
    std::size_t timeout = INFINITE;
    if(str == _T("INFINITE"))
        return timeout;
    auto p_begin = str.c_str();
    TCHAR* p_end = nullptr;
    timeout = static_cast<std::size_t>(_tcstol(p_begin, &p_end, 10));
    if((timeout == 0) || !p_end || (*p_end != _T('\0')))
        THROW("Invalid timeout string");
    return timeout;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(argc <= 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid command line:" << "\n";
        std::cout << "\t" << "<timeout msecs> (or INFINITE) <exe> <arg0> <arg1> ..." << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try {
        std::size_t timeout = ParseTimeout(argv[1]);
        string_t cmd_line;
        if(_tcslen(argv[2]) == 0)
            THROW("Executable path is empty");

        for(int i = 2; i < argc; ++i)
        {
#if(1)
            ArgvQuote(argv[i], cmd_line, true);
#else
            cmd_line.append(argv[i]);
#endif
            if(i < (argc - 1))
                cmd_line.push_back(_T(' '));
        }

        auto content = ConsoleOutFromExec(cmd_line, timeout);
        std::cout << content << "\n";
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see there is nothing new (in comparison to the link above), just using RAII for more clear code and without stdin redirection (`ArgvQuote()` is from [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx)).

Next, if I will run:

- `child_read.exe INFINITE cmd.exe /c whoami`
- `child_read.exe INFINITE cmd.exe /c ipconfig`

everything works fine. But next command:

- `child_read.exe INFINITE cmd.exe /c ipconfig /all`

will freeze execution. Debugger shows that the problem is that `::WaitForSingleObject()` never returns. And, actually, `ipconfig` process alive:
[image: ipconfig /all execution]

This happens for Windows 8.1 and above, but on Windows 7 everything works fine without `ipconfig` freeze !! Why ?
Btw, If I remove waiting for process and start reading from pipe - everything  works and I will have application output (but I need to have execution timeout)!

Can someone explain why this happens ? is this relative to `ipconfig /all` command only or I have something wrong in the code and this can happen with any other application too ?

(Everything that I found in the google/stackoverflow is relative to stuck if stdin is redirected too...)

Comment: What's the `ArgvQuote`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alfm, `ArgvQuote()` is from this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx)

Comment: Oh, now I see that in your text. I expected it in the code. I think that code will not work with ANSI version of your program: try to build the program with `ANSI` defined (and `UNICODE` not defined). I.e. all that `T` stuff is for nothign.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, compiled with `cl /EHsc /nologo /W4 /MTd -DANSI` - the situation is the same

Comment: My bad, should be `_ANSI`, not `ANSI` (the macros for the runtime lib have leading underscore). Then, it doesn't compile. I'm now trying it, compiled for unicode with g++, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Note to self: **Before testing SO code one should have a cup of coffee**. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, sorry for my absense. You have compilation error because there is no `ArgvQuote()` for `char`. I updated the code, so now you can compile it with `cl /EHsc /nologo /W4 /MTd -D_ANSI`. And, yes, still the same....

Comment: Oh good, code that compiles.  Well, one problem is that the quoter quotes too aggressively, e.g. `b INFINITE cmd /c assoc` (where `b` is your program) fails. This may not necessarily be connected to the problem you're asking about, but it needs attention.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, yes, quoter was the first attempt to figure out the problem (I thought that maybe something wrong with child's process arguments). Now it's looks like that the problem is in another place (without `ArgvQuote()` it freeze too). Btw, `INFINITE cmd.exe /c assoc` does not work on Windows 7 too

Comment: OK, now I have a cup of coffee and the first I tried now was just to invoke `tasklist`. That hangs, while `whoami` works. Sort of indicates that it's just too much output that's the problem. I think I'll look at the code. ;-)

Comment: You need to replace the infinite wait wait a wait-and-read loop. A pipe doesn't have an infinite buffer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, and if there will be no EOF (or any data on child stdout) `::ReadFile()` will block forever. I did wait on process to make sure that ::ReadFile() will return control. Have you any suggestions ? And thanks for all )

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, looks like I need [`PeekNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779(v=vs.85).aspx) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @Cheers and hth. - Alf. As he said in the comments:

> You need to replace the infinite wait wait a wait-and-read loop. A
>   pipe doesn't have an infinite buffer. –

To avoid `::ReadFile()` block if there is no data on child process console, need to use [`PeekNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779(v=vs.85).aspx) function, that will tell us how many bytes available in the pipe (child process console, in our case). So, here is fixed `ReadFromPipe()` function from my question:

```
std::string ReadFromPipe(
    handle_ptr&& std_out, // handle to child console
    handle_ptr&& wait_on, // handle to child process
    std::size_t timeout_msecs,
    bool* timeout)
{
    std::string content;
    DWORD read = 0;
    DWORD bytes_available = 0;
    DWORD total_read = 0;
    CHAR buf[1 * 1024] = {};
    BOOL done = FALSE;
    std::size_t current_waittime = 0;

    while(!done)
    {
        bytes_available = static_cast<DWORD>(-1);
        switch(::WaitForSingleObject(wait_on.get(), 1))
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            if(!::PeekNamedPipe(std_out.get(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, &bytes_available, nullptr) &&
                (::GetLastError() != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE))
                    THROW_E("PeekNamedPipe()");
            break;
        }

        total_read = 0;
        while(total_read < bytes_available)
        {
            DWORD count = (std::min)(static_cast<DWORD>(_countof(buf)), static_cast<DWORD>(bytes_available - total_read));
            if(!::ReadFile(std_out.get(), buf, count, &read, nullptr) &&
                (::GetLastError() != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE))
                THROW_E("ReadFile()");
            else if(read == 0)
            {
                done = TRUE;
                break;
            }

            content.append(buf, read);
            total_read += read;
        }

        if(++current_waittime >= timeout_msecs)
        {
            *timeout = true;
            content.clear();
            break;
        }
    }

    return content;
}
```

And here is all code together:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <cassert>

#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using string_t = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;

#define THROW_E(X) THROW((X) + std::string(": ") + std::to_string(::GetLastError()))
#define THROW(X) throw std::runtime_error{(X)}

namespace {

using handle_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, decltype(&::CloseHandle)>;

handle_ptr CreateHandlePtr(HANDLE h)
{
    return handle_ptr{h, &::CloseHandle};
}

handle_ptr CreateChildProcess(string_t cmd_line, handle_ptr&& std_out, const string_t& dir)
{
    assert(!cmd_line.empty());
    assert(std_out.get());

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = std_out.get();
    si.hStdOutput = std_out.get();
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

    LPTSTR p_cmd_line = &cmd_line[0];
    auto created = CreateProcess(NULL, 
        p_cmd_line,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        TRUE, // Handles are inherited 
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        NULL, // Use parent's environment 
        dir.empty() ? nullptr : dir.c_str(),
        &si,
        &pi);
    if(!created)
        THROW_E("CreateProcess()");

    std_out.reset();
    ::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return CreateHandlePtr(pi.hProcess);
}

std::string ReadFromPipe(
    handle_ptr&& std_out, // handle to child console
    handle_ptr&& wait_on, // handle to child process
    std::size_t timeout_msecs,
    bool* timeout)
{
    std::string content;
    DWORD read = 0;
    DWORD bytes_available = 0;
    DWORD total_read = 0;
    CHAR buf[1 * 1024] = {};
    BOOL done = FALSE;
    std::size_t current_waittime = 0;

    while(!done)
    {
        bytes_available = static_cast<DWORD>(-1);
        switch(::WaitForSingleObject(wait_on.get(), 1))
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            if(!::PeekNamedPipe(std_out.get(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, &bytes_available, nullptr) &&
                (::GetLastError() != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE))
                    THROW_E("PeekNamedPipe()");
            break;
        }

        total_read = 0;
        while(total_read < bytes_available)
        {
            DWORD count = (std::min)(static_cast<DWORD>(_countof(buf)), static_cast<DWORD>(bytes_available - total_read));
            if(!::ReadFile(std_out.get(), buf, count, &read, nullptr) &&
                (::GetLastError() != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE))
                THROW_E("ReadFile()");
            else if(read == 0)
            {
                done = TRUE;
                break;
            }

            content.append(buf, read);
            total_read += read;
        }

        if(++current_waittime >= timeout_msecs)
        {
            *timeout = true;
            content.clear();
            break;
        }
    }

    return content;
}

} // namespace

std::string ConsoleOutFromExec(const string_t& cmd_line, std::size_t timeout_msecs = INFINITE,
    const string_t& directory = string_t{})
{
    auto child_stdout_r = CreateHandlePtr(nullptr);
    auto child_stdout_w = CreateHandlePtr(nullptr);
    {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {};
        sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

        HANDLE raw_child_stdout_r = nullptr;
        HANDLE raw_child_stdout_w = nullptr;
        if(!::CreatePipe(&raw_child_stdout_r, &raw_child_stdout_w, &sa, 0))
            THROW_E("CreatePipe()");
        child_stdout_r = CreateHandlePtr(raw_child_stdout_r);
        child_stdout_w = CreateHandlePtr(raw_child_stdout_w);

        if(!::SetHandleInformation(child_stdout_r.get(), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
            THROW_E("SetHandleInformation()");
    }

    auto child_proc = CreateChildProcess(cmd_line, std::move(child_stdout_w), directory);

    bool timeout = false;
    auto content = ReadFromPipe(std::move(child_stdout_r), std::move(child_proc), timeout_msecs, &timeout);
    if(timeout)
        THROW("Execution timeout");
    return content;
}

std::size_t ParseTimeout(const string_t& str)
{
    std::size_t timeout = INFINITE;
    if(str == _T("INFINITE"))
        return timeout;
    auto p_begin = str.c_str();
    TCHAR* p_end = nullptr;
    timeout = static_cast<std::size_t>(_tcstol(p_begin, &p_end, 10));
    if((timeout == 0) || !p_end || (*p_end != _T('\0')))
        THROW("Invalid timeout string");
    return timeout;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(argc <= 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid command line:" << "\n";
        std::cout << "\t" << "<timeout msecs> (or INFINITE) <exe> <arg0> <arg1> ..." << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try {
        std::size_t timeout = ParseTimeout(argv[1]);
        string_t cmd_line;
        if(_tcslen(argv[2]) == 0)
            THROW("Executable path is empty");

        for(int i = 2; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            // TODO: quote arguments correctly
            cmd_line.append(argv[i]);
            if(i < (argc - 1))
                cmd_line.push_back(_T(' '));
        }

        auto content = ConsoleOutFromExec(cmd_line, timeout);
        std::cout << content << "\n";
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Again, **many thanks** to @Cheers and hth. - Alf for the help !